# How to create a shape from string name in Orchard?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I would like to create a base ContentPart driver class that can use string values to define a shape. This is not the exact code I am going for, but should show the general idea of what I am hoping to do.

Instead of the following:

```
protected override DriverResult Display(ProductPart, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    return this.ContentShape("Parts_Product",
        () => shapeHelper.Parts_Product());
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
protected override DriverResult Display(ProductPart, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    return this.ContentShape("Parts_Product",
        () => shapeHelper["Parts_Product"]());
}
```

Is there any way to use string names with shapeHelpers to generate shapes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible.

The dynamic `shapeHelper` object is an instance of `IShapeFactory`. This interface provides methods for doing exactly what you want.

Instead of using the dynamic method call `shapeHelper.Parts_Product()`, just use one of the provided `Create` method overloads, eg. `shapeHelper.Create("Parts_Product")`. 
*In fact, this is exactly what happens under the hood when you call the dynamic method.*

In the end, your whole example could look like:

```
protected override DriverResult Display(
    ProductPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    // It's better to cast shapeHelper to IShapeFactory first 
    // to avoid dynamic dispatch
    return this.ContentShape("Parts_Product",
        () => ((IShapeFactory)shapeHelper).Create("Parts_Product"));
}
```